# Force the user to log in right on the front page in Next JS (13 or 14)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I've made a classic dashboard app in Next.js 13 with pages routerm, which has all its pages behind the /dashboard route, so they look like /dashboard/users, /dashboard/orders etc. I'd like to make sure that when the user opens the website, there's going to be a fork function that would either send him to the /dashboard page if he's logged in, or send him to the login page if he's not. I've tried the regular useEffect function to do this, but it keeps crashing.

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Index() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();

  useEffect(() => {}, []);
  if (status === "authenticated") {
    redirect("/dashboard");
  } else {
    redirect("/api/auth/signin");
  }
  return <></>;
}
```

I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation, which only tells me how to handle route protection and authentication, but nothing like this. Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that the useEffect hook is empty, and the redirection logic is outside the useEffect block. You should perform the redirection inside the useEffect hook, and make sure that the redirect function is asynchronous. Here's the corrected code:

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Index() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "authenticated") {
      redirect("/dashboard");
    } else {
      redirect("/api/auth/signin");
    }
  }, [status]);

  return <></>;
}
```